# Get the data from Multi line Text field and set it to text area line by line

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, rest, jquery, multiline-text-field

I have a multi line rich text field and I want to get the data from column and set in text area line by line.

I tried Splitting but I need another solution if possible.

Comment: Please add more details to your question. post the code you tried here if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily by using p tag, i was also stucked on the same problem:
HTML part: `<p id="location_of_work"></p>`
Code:
**$('#location_of_work').text(form1.location_of_work);**
here **form1** is my array from where i am getting values 
location_of_work: column name

Comment: when we fetch the data <br> tag also comes.So in array we have to do splitting?

Comment: You don't need to add <br> only define width, when it will reach end of width, data will shift to another line

Answer (score 0):

We can use REST API to get the multiple line of text field data, then set the text to textarea using jQuery. The following example code for your reference.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var listTitle="CustomList";
    var fieldName="MultipleText";
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/items",
        type: "GET",               
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var text="";
            $.each(data.d.results,function(i,item){
                text+=$(item[fieldName]).text()+"\n";
            });
            $("#message").val(text);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
});
</script> 
<textarea id="message" rows="6" cols="80">
</textarea>
```